# Captions on with every video even if I switch it of

Tags: youtube

Ever since youtube last update captions with every video auto on, eventhough I switch it of in my settings. On a different noteI find the captions very irritating because the captions are realy bad not sync different of what the people say in the video and captions to slow. That is way I do not want any captions in my videos.

Answer (score 1):

I u installed all the YouTube updates in the app store and now it seems to work OK, no more irritating captions.

Comment: This would have been my suggestion too.

Since YouTube is often installed as a system app you are able to uninstall any updates through setting or through the Play store.

Clearing cache and data through app settings is also a possible solution as this will remove any settings and return the app to its default.